# DAX measure to find the max value of another measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have a tracking IT system to monitor the real time location of the trucks from our suppliers to us. This is still being deployed and so some are not tracked yet. The list looks something like this, ignore other irrelevant fields:

[image]

I have created some simple measures such as:

- trips = Count(DT_Tracking[Supplier])
- tracked_trips = calculate(count(DT_Tracking[Tracked]),not(DT_Tracking[Tracked]=""))+0
- ratio = divide(tracked_trips/trips)

When put on a visual it outputs what I would expect if I show the ratio:
[image]

Now I would like to get in a different visual the best week and the value of the best week for each supplier. For example, for supplier C it would be 93% and week 202110.

I guess there is a direct way to achieve that, I only managed to find it with an ugly workaround:

1. Outputted from PowerQuery a new table with all pairs of Supplier and Week
2. For each row, I then calculated trips, tracked trips and ratio of tracked trips.
3. In this table I calculated the highest ratio and the week with the highest ratio.

Then I used these two last values in a visual. But for sure there is a faster way to do that. Any hints about how to calculate this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trips = CALCULATE(COUNT(DT_Tracking[Supplier]), ALLEXCEPT(DT_Tracking, DT_Tracking[Week], DT_Tracking[Supplier]))

tracked_trips = CALCULATE(COUNT(DT_Tracking[Supplier]), FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(DT_Tracking, DT_Tracking[Week], DT_Tracking[Supplier]), DT_Tracking[Tracked] <> "")) + 0

ratio = divide(tracked_trips, trips)

result = 
var max_value = MAXX(ALLEXCEPT(DT_Tracking, DT_Tracking[Supplier]), [ratio])
return MAXX(DT_Tracking, IF([ratio]=max_value && max_value <> 0, max_value))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. :)